# Streaming Dataflow job restarting due to "autoscaling" attempts despite autoscalingAlgorithm is set to "None"

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have a dataflow job that is consistently restarting due to autoscaling attempts (according to the logs). We would see this log multiple times a day:

```
Autoscaling: Raised the number of workers to 1 so that the pipeline can catch up with its backlog and keep up with its input rate.
```

One confusing aspect of this is that there does not seem to be a corresponding log indicating workers are scaling down to 0, which seems to imply that the number of workers is already at 1 and these attempts just result in soft restarts.

The pipeline options below are set to values that (according to [Dataflow horizontal-autoscaling documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/horizontal-autoscaling)), should prevent autoscaling from being attempted.

| Pipeline Option | Value |
| --- | --- |
| `autoscalingAlgorithm` | `None` |
| `maxNumWorkers` | 1 |
| `numWorkers` | 1 |

Some other relevant job info details include:

- Streaming Engine: `enabled`
- Runner V2: `enabled`
- Vertical Autoscaling: `disabled`

I thought that in theory, setting both `maxNumWorkers` and `numWorkers` to 1 should prevent this but unfortunately that does not seem to be the case.